# iOS XML Parser memory leaks with KissXML

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, xml-parsing, kissxml

I've been confused by this memory problem for a few days. In my iOS project, i use KissXML as XML parser. My XML files are huge(15M). Now, the memory problem comes:

Here's my code

http connection finished part:

```
NSData *copyData = [NSData dataWithData:self.httpData];  //self.httpData-recieved from http connection.
dispatch_async(globalQueue,^{  //globalQueue-GCD global queue.
    [AIDXMLParser universalParser:copyData];  //Class method for XML Parser.
});
```

In API:universalParser of AIDXMLParser.m

```
DDXMLDocument *doc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];
[doc release];
```

When i run my app. I use [Activity Monitor] to catch my memory usage.

> Before : [Real memory size] is 40.7M
>
> After: [Real memory size is 63.1M

The increased memory (63.1M-40.7M) stays there forever.

Everything works well. I have tried using TBXML instead of KissXML. Use Instruments-Profile/Analyze for testing, but still no errors or no warnings.
I don't know where i am wrong.

Is anybody else facing the same problem?

Comment: Try self.httpData = nil;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the size of your NSData, try splitting your XML and do the parsing multiple time.

I hade the same issue with JSON of 10MB+.

Comment: Is it the only way? (- -!)
My NSData's size is not over 5MB+, but it get huge after generating NSData into XMLDocument.

Comment: OK, finally I find a way out - Change each XML file's format, make it smaller enough, and it will be better.